# Generating Functional in Momentum Space -- QFT

Tags: generating-functions, problem-solving, quantum-field-theory

Question attached:

[image]

inserting $\phi (x)= \int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^2}\phi(x)e^{-i k_u x^u}$
and similar for $J(x) $ / $J(k)$ into the action and then integrating over $k$ gives:

Solution attached:

[image]
I AM STUCK on this part, completing the square ; so I see we get back the term $\frac{-h}{i}J(k)\phi(-k)$ however don't we also get an additional identiical term $J(-k)\phi (k)$?

What has happened to this?!

Many thanks in advance.

2. Relevant equations

see above

3. The attempt at a solution

see above

Answer (score 0):

You pulled out a factor $1/2$, so you need to compensate by multiplying the $J(k)\phi(-k)$ term by $2$. Then use that
$$
2\int d^4k \, J(k)\phi(-k)=\int d^4k \, J(k)\phi(-k) + \int d^4k \, J(-k)\phi(k).
$$

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Where does $\int d^4 k J(k) \phi(-k) = \int d^4 k J(-k) \phi(k)$ come from however? (or from the definition of the fourier transform is it just a matter of which exponential term we decide goes with what, i.e. for both we have a $\exp^{ik^ux_u}$ and a $\exp^{-ik^ux_u}$?

Comment: @yourlazyphysicist It comes from a change of coordinates. For any integrable function $f$ and any non-singular $4\times 4$ matrix $M$, it holds true that $\int d^4k \, f(k) = \int d^4k \, \lvert \det M\rvert f(Mk)$. Take $M=-I$ for the case at hand.